# Error in NUnit Console: "WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported"

Tags: multithreading, nunit

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8065982/4794), I upgraded to version 2.6 of NUnit, and started getting a threading error.

> WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported

The tests run fine under the NUnit GUI, but fail on the console version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the new NUnit console version must have switched from multi-threaded apartment model to single-threaded. Anyway, there's a command-line switch to set it back to MTA. Here's the relevant section from my NAnt build script.

```
<exec program="nunit-console.exe" if="${nunit-in-path}">
  <arg file="../ZaberConsole/ZaberConsoleTest.nunit"/>
  <arg value="/apartment=MTA"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively try setting the [RequiresMTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresMTA&r=2.5) attribute on the assembly.
This worked for me.